# Image Title Attribute in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

just a question: how can I show the image title attribute in my logo? I'm using an SEO tool scanner that scanning for Title Attr of image and you can only add logo in customize setting can't edit it with HTML code.

Also, I have lots of logos on my banner that I also add in customize the setting how can I show the image title attr. of it. even I set up in the title tag in media

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the post id of the post you want to get in your URL. So, your URL (route) will be like this. where 9 is the post id.

https://wp.illuminosdigital.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/9

You can get more information here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#retrieve-a-post

Comment: Thank you for the answer I solved the issue thanks allot